# RuntimeError: Native library not available at mini_racer.dll Pyinstaller

Tags: python

Created standalone exe with pyinstaller give errors.

I am using py_mini_racer which using eval.
I don't know why its creating issue tho. I am using eval in code.

Comment: Getting this error ...   File "py_mini_racer\py_mini_racer.py", line 178, in __init__
  File "py_mini_racer\py_mini_racer.py", line 125, in _build_ext_handle
RuntimeError: Native library not available at mini_racer.dll

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I met the same problem, but using Mac M1
go to the issue part of the mini_racer, found there caught same question, and found for mac M1, the package is missing. May be you can go and see if the package is still there, though you are using windows.

https://github.com/sqreen/PyMiniRacer/issues/143

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32190593)